# What can cause "Access to database is denied by server administrator"

Tags: firebird, opensuse

A few days ago I started working with firebird on opensuse. When I try open the database by using monodevelop(C#), I get the error message:

> "access to database is denied by server administrator"

How can I solve this?

I am using firebird 2,5, opensuse 13.1, and monodevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a database in a location that is not allowed by the server configuration. There are two potential causes:

1. The value(s) of `DatabaseAccess` in `firebird.conf` do not include or explicitly deny the current location of the database.

   To fix this you either need to configure an alias and use the alias to connect, move the database to one of the allowed folders, or add an additional location to the configuration entry
2. the firebird user (the user running the server process) does not have access to the database file.

   To fix this you need to make sure that the firebird user of the server process (if connecting through the Firebird server), or your own user (if using embedded) has sufficient access rights to the database.

See also http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq39/ and http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.ConfiguringFirebird#DatabaseAccess